# reading .wav files using x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, file-io, x86, wav

Can anybody please tell me how I can read .wav files using X86 assembly?

Thanks a lot

Comment: the same way you would with any other language make system calls to the operating system top open and read the file, then using documentation for the wav file format parse through the file data.

Comment: I don't get it. I mean I know how to open a txt file using interrupts; how to read it; how to write in it. But how am I supposed to read a .wav file? I mean there's no interrupt for that in the instruction set.

Comment: @user2511906: If you know how to open and read a text file, why don't you apply the same method to wav files? The difference is in what you do with the data once you've read it.

Comment: So it'll just do? I mean, once I have opened the file, there are for instance samples and stuff (with the header specifications or without?)?

Comment: google wav file format

Comment: start with some other language then just port the code to asm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file and read the data. Since everything boils down to asm eventually, this is certainly possible.

There are variations which use WAV, but the original was 8 or 16-bit linear straight from the codec. You just need to read the header to get the width and frequency.